# 18:04 Lost desktop icon(s) after sudo apt-get upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, icons

I have lost icon(s) after running `sudo apt-get upgrade` on my ubuntu 18.04.

The systems is also slower now.

Would you like to help me to solve this problem?
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hotEH.png)
[log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urSAu.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYWzT.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to name exact package name with icons.
So I provide single long command to reinstall all icons-related packages:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep -i icon | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```

In the command above:

- `dpkg -l | grep -i icon | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}'` is a long pipe with:

  - `dpkg -l` shows the list of all packages;
  - `grep -i icon` shows all text lines with icons;
  - `grep ^ii` shows only installed packages;
  - `awk '{print $2}'` shows package names;
- `sudo apt install --reinstall $(...)` is used to reinstall packages from the output of `$(...)` command.

You can consult man-pages - `man dpkg`, `man apt`, `man grep`, `man awk` for details about used commands.